# Apache POI hsmf returning null for getMesssageDate

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, msg

I am trying to retrieve outlook message (.msg) properties using apache MAPIMessage API. I am able to retrieve other metadata like from, to , cc but when i am using getMessageDate method retrieve date it is returning null.

Any idea guys what might be the reason for this behavior?

Thanks and Regards
Durgesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the version of POI that you are using, there was a [similar fix](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57744) applied in release POI 3.13, so you may solve this by upgrading to the latest version.

If that does not solve your problem, please open a bug-report for POI with a sample mail-message to allow the developers to take a look at the format of the mail-message.

Comment: Thanks Centic, updating to POI 3.13 solved the issue.